# Generalizing a hidden semi-Markov model for trading

Tags: probability, mean-reversion, hidden-markov-model

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_semi-Markov_model):

> A hidden semi-Markov model (HSMM) is a statistical model with the same
> structure as a hidden Markov model except that the unobservable
> process is semi-Markov rather than Markov. This means that **the
> probability of there being a change in the hidden state depends on the
> amount of time that has elapsed since entry into the current state**.
> This is in contrast to hidden Markov models where there is a constant
> probability of changing state given survival in the state up to that
> time.

My high level understanding of these models is that the duration in a given state is modeled by its own matrix (i.e., discrete probabilities).  I'm wondering if the basic idea can be generalized for any continuous value.

For example, the S&P has moved down since the start of 2022, but has done so in a very oscillatory fashion:

[image]

Rather than using duration to inform state probabilities, I'm wondering if cumulative return within a given state could be used, which I think reflects the way actual traders read charts.

In plain English, traders look to take profits after an extended uptrend or look for buying opportunities after an extended downtrend.  Time is probably a factor here (i.e., a vanilla HSMM might have some value on its own), but the more important factor is cumulative returns in a given state.  Or maybe both time and cumulative returns could be considered.

The math on this is a little over my head at the moment, so I'm looking for any suggestions on how this type of model could be formulated.  The goal would be to take advantage of standard inputs that might be used for an HMM for trading (e.g., single period or short-duration returns, volatility, etc.) while also capturing cumulative state information.

Any suggestions on how to build such a model, reading material, etc. are appreciated.

Comment: Hi: generally, questions like will get a very scarce response because A) if you're onto something that actually works, no one will prefer that you  make progress with the idea because, generally speaking, the more people that have the same or similar model, the less effective it will be. B) if you're not onto something, then most people won't be familiar with what it is you are trying to do and therefore won't have much to say. I happen not to fall in either category because I didn't really follow the reasoning. This doesn't mean that it wasn't clear.

Comment: Yep, I've had that experience with asking general questions, but figured it worth a shot.  This would not be a standalone strategy but would be one component in something else I'm already doing, so I didn't mind putting it out there.  In general, I'd also like to learn to make custom Bayesian models, but I've struggled to put certain ideas into code, likely due to a lack of formal background.  I was hoping this question might help with learning to think along those lines.

Comment: A couple other things.  1) I've searched for papers where HSMMs are used for trading purposes and they are basically non-existent.  2) I think a hackish solution to this could be achieved by fitting one HMM on the data, then fitting a second HMM on the original data plus the cumulative returns within each state.  Or maybe using a peak finder algorithm with a given threshold and fitting a distribution to the returns between peaks/troughs.

Comment: I have zero experience with HMM's but James Hamilton, a respected time series econometrician, had a well received paper in the late 90's regarding "regime switching". Maybe that's something that you might want to look at.  Regime switching possesses a similar notion of being in a "regime" or "state".